# Django RedirectView that takes an argument

Tags: python, django, django-views

Need a view that takes an idea from the context and returns redirect url.

This code works fine:

```
class FooView(RedirectView):
    def get(self, request, id, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('foo_space:foo', urlconf='bar.system.urls'))
```

- In this case is there any reason to use RecirectView at all (while not View)?
- May be there is more appripriate way to do it? E.g. using get_redirect_url?

Comment: What you're doing is perfectly fine, but you are correct that you do not need a RedirectView to do it. I suppose using `get_redirect_url` is technically the preferred way. you could just put your `reverse(...` in there instead. If you need access to the context inside `get_redirect_url` see here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview

Comment: Can you please, specify how to get access to context from the get_redirect_url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely worthwhile. Check out what `RedirectView` does. For one, it redirects all methods by default `PUT`, `POST`, `HEAD` etc. while `View` would throw a `405` for everything but `get`

And definitely override `get_redirect_url` to take advantage of the above.

It could be simpler via setting the `pattern_name` attribute only, but it looks like you need the `urlconf` kwarg as well so this method may not work.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.RedirectView.pattern_name